# Return string when execute function

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a view:

```
Ext.define('DemoApp.view.Main', {
    //Some code here
    ...
    items: [{
        xtype: 'label',
        text: //<- I want to run some scripts then return a string to this.
    }]
})
```

I tried:

```
text: function() {
    return 'Test';
}
```

but nothing happened.

Please help!

Comment: Can you define the object and then, afterwards, run whatever code it is you want to fill the `text` field? Like `items[0].text = 'Test'`. As it stands, it seems that you are just setting `text` to be a function and not executing that function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

```
function getText(){
   if(someVariable==someValue){
     return 'text1';
   } else{
     return 'text2';
   }
};
Ext.define('DemoApp.view.Main', {
    //Some code here
    ...
    items: [{
        xtype: 'label',
        text: getText()
    }]
});
```

In this case, if you are writing the main definition as a separate file, `getText` function will become global function.

**Solution 2:**

```
Ext.define('DemoApp.view.Main', {
    //Some code here
    ...
    initComponent: function(){
        function getText(){
            if(someVariable==someValue){
               return 'text1';
            } else{
               return 'text2';
            }
        };
        this.items = [{
           xtype: 'label',
           text: getText()
        }];
        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much!

Comment: Worth noting that `Ext.define` accepts an anonymous function as an optional third parameter - allowing you to neatly resolve any imperative logic without polluting the global scope.

Answer (score 0):

One set of parentheses can make so much difference:

```
text: function() {
    return 'Test';
}()
```

Answer (score -1):

It works for me please check the below code.

```
 <script>
    function returntext(d){
        return d;
    }
    window.item = [{
        text: returntext("Name")
    }]
</script>
```